# How to use lodash without exposing "_." in a UI Framework? Like jQuery.noConflict()

Tags: javascript, lodash

Does lodash have a feature like jQuery.noConflict()?

I'm creating a UI Framework (in AngularJS) that allows teams to build plugins that work within the framework.  Within the framework, I'd like to use lodash, but I don't want to force on all plugin users that the _. is lodash.  I want them to be able to use _. for underscore or whatever.  Is there a way to do this in lodash?

Comment: Pretty sure lodash has its own noConflict method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo-dash has its own noConflict: [`_.noConflict()`](http://lodash.com/docs#noConflict)